Fill out empty cells in google sheet under a condition
I want to fill out empty cells in column B with the right codes. The rule is that the code must be the same for any email in the same group. Here groups are defined in column A: so each group consists of emails lying between the text "Email" in column A.
This is one example:
Input:

This is the output I want.


EDIT: Fixed formula to return empty if there is no code
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(e,A:A,k,B:B,r,ROW(e),c,COUNTIFS(e,"Email",r,"<="&r),
   ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IF(COUNTIFS(k,"<>",c,c),IF(e="Email",,SCAN(,SORT(k,c,1,1,1),
      LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c)))),),MAX(r*({e,k}<>"")),1)))



Here's one way to do this (enter this formula in row 1):
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IF(A:A="Email",,
   SCAN(,SORT(B:B,COUNTIFS(A:A,"Email",ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A:A)),1,1,1),
     LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c)))),MAX(ROW(A:B)*(A:B<>"")),1))


Explanation
We first label each group with:
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(A:A,"Email",ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A:A)))


Then we put each code on the top using SORT:

After this it's just a simple SCAN fill constrained to the last non-empty row of A:B.
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
  SCAN(,<array_with_codes_on_top>,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c)))),
  MAX(ROW(A:B)*(A:B<>"")),1)


Sorry, it did not work for me. This is my screenshot: https://i.postimg.cc/SxZf7Yjm/Screenshot-2024-04-06-at-23-18-19.png

can you share a link to the sheet in the screenshot with EDIT rights? If you don't want to expose your email, you can make a sample sheet and reproduce the issue there.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vze47NIsCNP0U2RuebY9tpxj7KwXx2xzrw8HR2fjgfA/edit#gid=242181152 This is the sheet.

the sheet is view only.

I modified it. Thank you.

your formulas expect ; instead of , as argument separators. =ARRAYFORMULA(LET(e;H:H;k;IF(ROW(e)=1;;I:I);ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IF(e="Email";;SCAN(;SORT(k;COUNTIFS(e;"Email";ROW(e);"<="&ROW(e));1;1;1);LAMBDA(a;c;IF(c="";a;c))));MAX(ROW(e)*({e\k}<>""));1)))

Thank you so much for your time and effort.

In your first formua: =ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IF(A:A="Email",,
SCAN(,SORT(B:B,COUNTIFS(A:A,"Email",ROW(A:A),"<="&ROW(A:A)),1,1,1),
LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c)))),MAX(ROW(A:B)*(A:B<>"")),1)) Could you modify it so that if the code in column B is empty then the output in column C is also empty as well?
